# Remove space between bars ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my code

```
    ggplot(df, aes(x=timepoint, y=mean, fill=group)) +
            geom_bar(position=position_dodge(.3), colour="black", stat="identity", width=0.3, , binwidth=0) +
            geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(.3), width=.25, aes(ymin=mean, ymax=mean+sem)) +
            scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FFFFFF", "#000000"), guide=FALSE) +
            theme_bw() +
            ylab(ylab) +
            xlab("") +
            # xlim("Baseline", "12w") +
            scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0), limits=c("Baseline","12w")) + 
            scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0) ) + 
            theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

This is MY output, which I DONT want, its too much space between "baseline" and "12w":

[image]

How to remove the space between the bars?

Thank you

df is like this:

```
df <- structure(list(group = c("a1.d.ffa.mean Dysglyc", "a1.c.ffa.mean Control", 
"b1.d.ffa.mean Dysglyc", "b1.c.ffa.mean Control"), timepoint = c("Baseline", 
"Baseline", "12w", "12w"), mean = c(1.913509, 2.181959, 2.742249, 
1.50846), sem = c(0.10663114, 0.08360294, 0.07890374, 0.08348542
), p.value = c(0.597738161, 1, 0.007885464, 1), p.value.t = c(0.04408, 
1, 0.2455049, 1)), .Names = c("group", "timepoint", "mean", "sem", 
"p.value", "p.value.t"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df

                  group timepoint     mean        sem     p.value p.value.t
1 a1.d.ffa.mean Dysglyc  Baseline 1.913509 0.10663114 0.597738161 0.0440800
2 a1.c.ffa.mean Control  Baseline 2.181959 0.08360294 1.000000000 1.0000000
3 b1.d.ffa.mean Dysglyc       12w 2.742249 0.07890374 0.007885464 0.2455049
4 b1.c.ffa.mean Control       12w 1.508460 0.08348542 1.000000000 1.0000000
```

Comment: Reduce the width of the plotting device.

Comment: @Roland Can I ask how? I cannot simply resize within R, that ratio aspects remains the same.

Comment: Could you provide the data used?

Comment: @Paulo Cardoso I have pasted the "df" data

Comment: Just resize the window before plotting or specify a width in `ggsave`.

Comment: That does not work. Im talking about the space between "baseline" and "12w". This space is set by the scale_x_discrete(). Its the space between the two limits "baseline" and "12w".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just adjust the widths:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=timepoint, y=mean, fill=group)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(0.9), colour="black", stat="identity", width=0.9, , binwidth=0) +
  geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(0.9), width=0.85, aes(ymin=mean, ymax=mean+sem)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, so use the relevel(), as suggested by @Paulo so to get baseline before 12w. Do you know how to remove the "ymin" from the error bar argument? I "hacked" it by setting it equal tot he mean, but its ugly.

Comment: I've answered your question. Please don't add additional questions in comments.

Comment: @nOOb [this link might be of help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723900/r-ggplot-suppress-bottom-of-error-bar-on-geom-bar#comment40220795_25723900)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
df <- structure(list(group = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("a1.c.ffa.mean Control", 
"a1.d.ffa.mean Dysglyc", "b1.c.ffa.mean Control", "b1.d.ffa.mean Dysglyc"
), class = "factor"), timepoint = structure(c(1L, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = c("Baseline", 
"12W"), class = "factor"), mean = c(1.913509, 2.181959, 2.742249, 
1.50846), sem = c(0.10663114, 0.08360294, 0.07890374, 0.08348542
), p.value = c(0.597738161, 1, 0.007885464, 1), p.value.t = c(0.04408, 
1, 0.2455049, 1)), .Names = c("group", "timepoint", "mean", "sem", 
"p.value", "p.value.t"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

reorder factor levels with

```
df$timepoint <- factor(df$timepoint, 
                       levels= c('Baseline', '12W'))
```

plot it

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(timepoint), y=mean, fill=group)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(.3), colour="black",
           stat="identity", width=0.3, , binwidth=0) +
  geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(.3), width=.25,
                aes(ymin=mean, ymax=mean+sem)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FFFFFF", "#000000","#FFFFFF", "#000000"),
                    guide=FALSE) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(list(x="", y='skeletal muscle FFA g/100g')) +
  # xlim("Baseline", "12w") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0) ) + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

[image: geom_bar]

Which is pretty close to your example...

Comment: Baseline should come before 12w. And still there is a huge gap between the baseline and 12w bars! I want baseline and 12w very close together. Thank you for the effort!

Comment: Please see updated picture in original post! Thank you again.