# Box plot, move boxes closer together

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have made a box plot with geometric means with the following code

```
bp.vals <- function(x, probs=c(0.05, 0.25, 0.75, .95)) {
    r <- quantile(x, probs=probs, na.rm=TRUE)
    r = c(r[1:2], exp(mean(log(x))), r[3:4])
    names(r) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
    r
}
ggplot(data_7m, aes(x=factor(BCG), y= IPVtype1_7m, fill=Group, width=0.4)) + 
     scale_fill_manual(values = c("dark grey", "light grey")) +
     stat_summary(fun.data=bp.vals, geom="boxplot", show.legend=F) + 
     labs(x="", y="GMC(IU/mL)")
```

I would like to move the boxes closer together, but cannot get it to work. I have tried space, position and par()function.

Does anybody know how to do this?
[Box plot geometric mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5t9N.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "move the boxes closer together"? Make the boxes wider? Decrease the width of the whole plot? Leave the plot exactly as it is but move the breaks of the x-axis closer to the middle?

Comment: You should probably change the `width` parameter.

Comment: Sorry, for not asking my question clearer.

I do not want to change the width of the boxes, but I want to decrease the width of the whole plot and especially the space between the two boxes.

Comment: Just change the size of the graphics window or even better use ggsave to export the plot with specified dimensions.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49041183/reduce-space-between-groups-of-bars-in-ggplot2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887066/remove-space-between-bars-ggplot2) seem related

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of a reproducible example, increase the width parameter. The width parameter is commonly used with geom_bar (e.g. `geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.9)` and geom_boxplot (`geom_boxplot(width=0.9)`).

```
ggplot(data_7m, aes(x=factor(BCG), y=IPVtype1_7m, fill=Group) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.9) +
     scale_fill_manual(values = c("dark grey", "light grey")) +
     labs(x="", y="GMC(IU/mL)"
```