# How to remove whitespace between bars in geom bar ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, removing-whitespace, geom

I would like to remove unnecessary white space in the following plot:
[image: figure]

Data:

```
structure(list(hypoxic2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), Season = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Pre", "Peak", "Post"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -185L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code used to generate plot above:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Season, ..count..)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = hypoxic2),
           position = position_dodge2(width = 1, preserve = "single")) + 
  #width = 0.9,
  #position = "dodge") + 
  ggtitle("TITLE") +
  labs(x="Season", fill = "Hypoxic (DO < 2 mg/L)", y = "Frequency") + 
  ggsci::scale_fill_igv(palette = "default") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Pre-Hypoxic",
                              "Peak-Hypoxic",
                              "Post-Hypoxic")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100),
                     expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, 0.01),
                                           add = c(0, 0))) +
  #scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100), breaks = seq(0,100,20),
  #                   expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, 0.01),
  #                                         add = c(0, 0)))
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.85,0.9),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, face = "bold", family = "Arial",
                                  size=15),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = 1),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_text(size=15),
        legend.title.align = 0.5,
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15, 
                                    margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0), 
                                    color = "black"),
        axis.title.x.top = element_text(size = 14, 
                                        margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 10, l = 0), 
                                        color = "black"),
        text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", 
                                   size = 10, 
                                   angle = 0, 
                                   vjust = 0.5, 
                                   hjust = 1,
                                   margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", 
                                   size = 12, 
                                   angle = 0, 
                                   vjust = 0, 
                                   hjust = 0.5,
                                   margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 0)),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size=18), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

I feel like there is a lot of wasted space here. How do I remove some of the white space without completely putting all the bars together?
Can I achieve this without increasing bar width?

Can I remove some of the white space (black ink in the figure below)?:
[image: what I would like to remove]

I looked at other questions on here, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887066/remove-space-between-bars-ggplot2), but can't get it to work.

Thank you!

Comment: Changing `position_dodge2` to `position_dodge` will basically get you there. However, the space between Pre-Hypoxic and Peak-Hypoxic will remain because that is where the 'Yes' group's bar is located.

Comment: I did try that but it makes it look odd since it shifts the bars for 'Pre-Hypoxic' and 'Post-Hypoxic' to the left while keeping the 'Peak-Hypoxic' where it is (like you mentioned) so it makes it look worse.. thanks for the input though, I was curious if there was a way of getting rid of that white space that I hadn't thought of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0.3))` it will reduce space on two sides.
I have changed the `legend.position = c(0.6,0.9)` as well.
[image]