# Show only ymax in error bars ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

A quick question I cannot for the life find the answer to:

Just look at the error bar argument for ggplot2, how can I remove the `ymin` from `aes()`?

I want my plots as simple as possible and I feel its enough to see the ymax.

```
geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(0.8), width=.6, aes(ymin=mean+sem, ymax=mean+sem), size=4)
```

This is what I want:

http://forums.ni.com/t5/DIAdem-Idea-Exchange/Error-bars-for-a-Bar-Plot/idi-p/1682644

Comment: [an answer in the comments to this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723900/r-ggplot-suppress-bottom-of-error-bar-on-geom-bar#comment40220795_25723900)

Comment: Following up on user20650, you might want to plot the errorbar first, and then plot the barplot on top.