# Error bars for barplot only in one direction

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart, data-visualization

Is it possible to adjust errorbars in ggplot2 so that they are plotted only in one direction (e.g. only upwards but not downwards)?

```
df <- data.frame(trt = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2)), resp = c(1, 5, 3, 4),
                 group = factor(c(1, 2, 1, 2)), se = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2))
df2 <- df[c(1,3), ]

limits <- aes(ymax = resp + se, ymin = resp - se)
dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.9)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(fill = group, y = resp, x = trt))
p + geom_bar(position = dodge, stat = "identity") +
    geom_errorbar(limits, position = dodge, width = 0.25)
```

[image: Rplot]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An easy work-around would be to plot the error bars first:

```
p +
  geom_errorbar(limits, position = dodge, width=0.25) +
  geom_bar(position = dodge, stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: That worked for me, and is by far the simplest solution I have found to this problem. Thank you!!

Answer (score 9):

It's actually pretty easy to implement this for use in the general case (where you can't hide the lower error bar under another plot element) now that they've made it easy to extend `ggplot2` with custom `geom`s.

Copy the code from `geom_errorbar` from the github repository for `ggplot2` into a new .R file. Then make a few modifications, as follows:

```
geom_uperrorbar <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL,
   stat = "identity", position = "identity",
   ...,
   na.rm = FALSE,
   show.legend = NA,
   inherit.aes = TRUE) {
   layer(
      data = data,
      mapping = mapping,
      stat = stat,
      geom = GeomUperrorbar,
      position = position,
      show.legend = show.legend,
      inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
      params = list(
         na.rm = na.rm,
         ...
      )
   )
}
```

The only two changes necessary above were to change `geom_errorbar` to `geom_uperrorbar` and `geom = GeomErrorbar` to `geom = GeomUperrorbar`.

```
GeomUperrorbar <- ggproto("GeomUperrorbar", Geom,
   default_aes = aes(colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = 1, width = 0.5,
      alpha = NA),

   draw_key = draw_key_path,
```

Note that this comment is interrupting partway through a function which continues in the code blocks below. Above we just changed `GeomErrorbar` to `GeomUperrorbar` twice.

```
   required_aes = c("x", "y", "ymax"),

   setup_data = function(data, params) {
      data$width <- data$width %||%
         params$width %||% (resolution(data$x, FALSE) * 0.9)

      transform(data,
         xmin = x - width / 2, xmax = x + width / 2, width = NULL
      )
   },
```

Interrupting the function again. Above we changed the required aesthetics to be `x`, `y` and `ymax`, i.e. replacing `ymin` with `y`. We need `y` to start the vertical line there (instead of at `ymin`) and we no longer need `ymin` because there's not going to be a horizontal line there.

```
   draw_panel = function(data, panel_scales, coord, width = NULL) {
      GeomPath$draw_panel(data.frame(
         x = as.vector(rbind(data$xmin, data$xmax, NA, data$x,   data$x)),
         y = as.vector(rbind(data$ymax, data$ymax, NA, data$ymax, data$y)),
         colour = rep(data$colour, each = 5),
         alpha = rep(data$alpha, each = 5),
         size = rep(data$size, each = 5),
         linetype = rep(data$linetype, each = 5),
         group = rep(1:(nrow(data)), each = 5),
         stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
         row.names = 1:(nrow(data) * 5)
      ), panel_scales, coord)
   }
)
```

Here we removed the last three elements of the vectors passed to `x` and `y`, which were for the lower error bar. In addition, we changed the last element from `ymin` to `y`, because we want the line to start at `y`, not `ymin`.

```
"%||%" <- function(a, b) {
   if (!is.null(a)) a else b
}
```

This last bit is just a convenience function used in the code that needs to be defined.

If you source the document including all of this code, then you can use `geom_uperrorbar` just like `geom_errorbar`, or even pass `geom = "uperrorbar"` to `stat_summary`, using `y` instead of `ymin`.

Comment: FWIW, that last bit (`%||%`) is now easily available in `purrr`.

Comment: This is the best solution!

Answer (score 7):

Henrik's advice is excellent in this case, but I would suggest that you take a look at where the upper and lower limits are set.

```
 limits <- aes(ymax = resp + se, ymin = resp - se)
```

In that line, you explicitly tell ggplot to put the lower extension by setting ymin as `resp - se`; if you just set it as `resp`, then you'd have only the upper extension.

```
 limits <- aes(ymax = resp + se, ymin = resp)
```

... although you'd also have a black line at the top of the bar. To make this look cleaner, you could add a black outline to the entire bar.

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(fill = group, y = resp, x = trt))+
  geom_bar(position = dodge, stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(position = dodge, stat = "identity", 
           color="black", show_guide=FALSE)+
  geom_errorbar(limits, position = dodge, width = 0.25)
p
```

[image: bar plot]

Notice how I duplicated the bar plot layer, but with a "black" color, which adds that outline. The legend was turned off in the colored layer because I personally prefer to avoid the diagonal lines in the legend.

Answer (score 3):

Henriks answer works if all of the bars are larger than the error bars. If you have error bars that are larger than your data bars, however, the tail end of the 'bottom' tail (negative error bar for positive data bar or vice versa) will be seen because it will cross the 0 y axis. If all of your data are in the same direction, you can set your limits ymin equal to 0.

The problem with this approach is that if you have mixed data bars (some positive and some negative) you can't set a limit to 0. For example, if the original data were:

```
df <- data.frame(trt = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2)), resp = c(1, 5, -3, 4),
             group = factor(c(1, 2, 1, 2)), se = c(2, 0.3, 4, 0.2))
df2 <- df[c(1,3), ]

limits <- aes(ymax = resp + se, ymin = resp - se)
dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.9)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(fill = group, y = resp, x = trt))
p + geom_errorbar(limits, position = dodge, width = 0.25) +
    geom_bar(position = dodge, stat = "identity")
```

The resulting plot would have error bars that extend beneath trt 1, group 1 and above trt 2, group1.

This can be fixed by adjusting the limit statment with an ifelse() clause:

```
limits <- aes(ymax = ifelse(resp>0,resp + se,resp/2),
              ymin = ifelse(resp<0,resp - se,resp/2))

p + geom_errorbar(limits, position = dodge, width = 0.25) +
    geom_bar(position = dodge, stat = "identity")
```

In this case, if the data are positive, the error bar max remains as normal, but the error bar min is adjusted to half of the databar height, so it remains hidden behind the databar.

Comment: The solution is neat but we see a thin black line for the error bar where it touches the bar (and if geom_point is used instead). The solution refered to by @Robert Wagner is suitable for other geom.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this solution:

[R ggplot: suppress bottom of error bar on geom_bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723900/r-ggplot-suppress-bottom-of-error-bar-on-geom-bar/34200761#34200761)

You just make your min/max both your upper limit and overlay a geom_linerange. Super hacky and clever